# Filter data $this->db->like or $this->db->or_like not working with kecamatan dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter-3

I was stuck in my feature for my web application, I have 4 menu filters for filtering data, fungsi_bangunan, jenis_bangunan is perfectly working, and desa/kelurahan is good to because I'm using javascript in json for populated that data when I select kecamatan and then select desa/kelurahan is working to, but when I use kecamatan filter data does not showing, the query builder I think is correctly but I cannot find the something wrong about this my problem, so maybe you guys can help me, what the solution, I use php and codeigniter framework for my project,

here the model code:

```
public function filter_data($filter) {
    $this->db->like('jenis_kegiatan',$filter);
    $this->db->or_like('fungsi_bangunan',$filter);
    $this->db->or_like('kecamatan',$filter);
    $this->db->or_like('desa_kel',$filter);
    $query = $this->db->get('permo_pdrt');
return $query->result();
}
```

and controller :

```
 public function filterkeyword() {
   $filter = $this->input->post('filter');
   $data['results'] = $this->model->filter_data($filter);
   $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
 }
```

and this view filter :

```
 <div class="row">
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>pdrtcrud/filterkeyword" method="post">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control form-inline" id="pilih_kecamatan" name="filter">
            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Pilih Kecamatan</option>
            <option value="Babakan Madang">Babakan Madang</option>
            <option value="Bojonggede">Bojonggede</option>
            <option value="Caringin">Caringin</option>
            <option value="Cariu">Cariu</option>
            <option value="Ciampea">Ciampea</option>
            <option value="Ciawi">Ciawi</option>
            <option value="Cibinong">Cibinong</option>
            <option value="Cibungbulang">Cibungbulang</option>
            <option value="Cigombong">Cigombong</option>
            <option value="Cigudeg">Cigudeg</option>
            <option value="Cijeruk">Cijeruk</option>
            <option value="Cileungsi">Cileungsi</option>
            <option value="Ciomas">Ciomas</option>
            <option value="Cisarua">Cisarua</option>
            <option value="Ciseeng">Ciseeng</option>
            <option value="Citereup">Citereup</option>
            <option value="Dramaga">Dramaga</option>
            <option value="Gunung Putri">Gunung Putri</option>
            <option value="Gunung Sindur">Gunung Sindur</option>
            <option value="Jasinga">Jasinga</option>
            <option value="Jonggol">Jonggol</option>
            <option value="Kemang">Kemang</option>
            <option value="Klapanunggal">Klapanunggal</option>
            <option value="Leuwiliang">Leuwiliang</option>
            <option value="Leuwisadeng">Leuwisadeng</option>
            <option value="Megamendung">Megamendung</option>
            <option value="Nanggung">Nanggung</option>
            <option value="Pamijahan">Pamijahan</option>
            <option value="Parung">Parung</option>
            <option value="Parung Panjang">Parung Panjang</option>
            <option value="Ranca Bungur">Ranca Bungur</option>
            <option value="Rumpin">Rumpin</option>
            <option value="Sukajaya">Sukajaya</option>
            <option value="Sukamakmur">Sukamakmur</option>
            <option value="Sukaraja">Sukaraja</option>
            <option value="Tajur halang">Tajur halang</option>
            <option value="Tamansari">Tamansari</option>
            <option value="Tanjungsari">Tanjungsari</option>
            <option value="Tenjo">Tenjo</option>
            <option value="Tenjolaya">Tenjolaya</option>                
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control form-inline" id="pilih_desa_kel" name="filter">
            <option>Pilih Desa/Kelurahan</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control form-inline" name="filter">
            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Jenis Kegiatan</option>
            <option value="Rumah Tinggal">Rumah Tinggal</option>
            <option value="Apartemen">Apartemen</option>
            <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
            <option value="Kantor Swasta">Kantor Swasta</option>
            <option value="Kantor Pemerintah">Kantor Pemerintah</option>
            <option value="Gedung Badan Usaha Pemerintah">Gedung Badan Usaha Pemerintah</option>
            <option value="Rumah Kantor">Rumah Kantor</option>
            <option value="Bank">Bank</option>
            <option value="Toko">Toko</option>
            <option value="Rumah Toko">Rumah Toko</option>
            <option value="Rumah Makan">Rumah Makan</option>
            <option value="Restoran">Restoran</option>
            <option value="Warung">Warung</option>
            <option value="Kios">Kios</option>
            <option value="Pasar Tradisional">Pasar Tradisional</option>
            <option value="Minimarket">Minimarket</option>
            <option value="SuperMarket">SuperMarket</option>
            <option value="Fasilitas Rekreasi">Fasilitas Rekreasi</option>
            <option value="SPBU">SPBU</option>
            <option value="SPBG">SPBG</option>
            <option value="Bengkel">Bengkel</option>
            <option value="Showroom">Showroom</option>
            <option value="Pool Kendaraan">Pool Kendaraan</option>
            <option value="Gedung Parkir">Gedung Parkir</option>
            <option value="Gudang">Gudang</option>
            <option value="Instalasi Pengolahan">Instalasi Pengolahan</option>
            <option value="Instalasi Jaringan Listrik">Instalasi Jaringan Listrik</option>
            <option value="Instalasi Telekomunikasi">Instalasi Telekomunikasi</option>
            <option value="Instalasi Jaringan Gas">Instalasi Jaringan Gas</option>
            <option value="Sarana Pendidikan">Sarana Pendidikan</option>
            <option value="Sarana Ibadah">Sarana Ibadah</option>
            <option value="Gedung Olahraga">Gedung Olahraga</option>
            <option value="Gedung Olahraga">Gedung Olahraga</option>
            <option value="Rumah Sakit">Rumah Sakit</option>
            <option value="Klinik">Klinik</option>
            <option value="Balai Pengobatan Lainnya">Balai Pengobatan Lainnya</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control form-inline" name="filter">
            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Fungsi Bangunan</option>
            <option value="Hunian">Hunian</option>
            <option value="Usaha">Usaha</option>
            <option value="Keagmaan">Keagamaan</option>
            <option value="Sosial Budaya">Sosial Budaya</option>
            <option value="Campuran">Campuran</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="filter">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you checked the logs for error , or if you can't detect any error try logging the query in model  log_message('ERROR',$this->db->last_query()), and from logs copy the query 

 and run in Mysql/database you are using, check if query is giving back the desire results.

Comment: I found this `SELECT * FROM `permo_pdrt` WHERE `jenis_kegiatan` LIKE '%Pilih Desa/Kelurahan%' ESCAPE '!' OR `fungsi_bangunan` LIKE '%Pilih Desa/Kelurahan%' ESCAPE '!' OR `kecamatan` LIKE '%Pilih Desa/Kelurahan%' ESCAPE '!' OR `desa_kel` LIKE '%Pilih Desa/Kelurahan%' ESCAPE '!' ` I'm using just you told me, $this->db->last_query() in view and I find this strange query

Comment: So, you should use this query and run manually in your MYSQL and check whether you are getting any result back , if not then then your code is working fine , you need to adjust the logic to get the correct query running and print desired results

Comment: thanks for that query , I mean try logging that very help me, and I have been fixed my error, so that's query is correct but, I found in my database in in coloumne desa/kel and kecamatan in wrong position in html, so that's query cannot find data what I wanted, and I change the position in view and get the query :
`SELECT * FROM `permo_pdrt` WHERE `jenis_kegiatan` LIKE '%Cariu%' ESCAPE '!' OR `fungsi_bangunan` LIKE '%Cariu%' ESCAPE '!' OR `kecamatan` LIKE '%Cariu%' ESCAPE '!' OR `desa_kel` LIKE '%Cariu%' ESCAPE '!' `